# Containing nested inline elements

Tags: html, css

I have an inline element nested within another inline element. In this case I am using a `b` element nested within a `label`. Now when I give both elements a border, I expect the outer element to fully contain the inner element. But when I apply some padding to the inner element, it ends up sticking out of it's parent. I must admit that after almost 2 decades of HTML/CSS, I still don't understand why this happens. Can anyone here:

1. Explain why this happens
2. Propose a fix

I want both borders to align exactly, without having to specify any dimensions on the `label`.

```css
label {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

b {
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<label><b>TEST</b></label>
```

You might think that `label` has some magic that causes this, but AFAICT this happens with all inline elements. For example, when using `span` instead of label, we get the exact same effect:

```css
span {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

b {
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<span><b>TEST</b></span>
```

Comment: inline-block to parent element and the child

Comment: also, `inline-block` the parent *and* the child is not a very scalable solution. What if I don't know in advance what content will be in my container? Plus I still have no explanation why this happens... I guess I'm just dumb or something.

Comment: don't judge the time of closing a question, judge the duplicate instead. No need to bring the *unwelcome stuff* to justify that I am doing bad and you are a victim. Read the duplicate and if you think it's not suitable to your question, edit to say *why* (I alos close questions in less than 1min ...)

Comment: Maybe you can explain how the dupe answers my first question of *why* this happens?

Comment: two answers explain this and using link to the Specification and if you check that link you can also read : *The vertical padding, border and margin of an inline, non-replaced box start at the top and bottom of the content area, and has nothing to do with the 'line-height'. But only the 'line-height' is used when calculating the height of the line box.* ... I will add more duplicates, there is more

Comment: @TemaniAfif The dupe question seems related, I certainly agree. But it is imho not a dupe. I am specifically asking about *nested* inline elements and containment. The dupe is about margin/padding top/bottom on inline elements. Can I beg you to reconsider closing and give my question a chance to get some answers? Please?

Comment: now you have 5 duplicates. The margin behave the same as padding that's why you will find it in the duplicate (the only difference is that backgroud/border won't apply to margin) and nesting inline elements will change nothing to the behavior your are facing.